# Post JSON to backend

Tags: java, json, post, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot application and now want to post the user details into the backend.I am posting a Json data to the backend by following code:

```
@RestController
    public class  DataInsertController {


        @RequestMapping(value = "data/api", consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<HostResponse> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody Host host )  {

            System.out.println(host.getName());

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new HostResponse("token"));
        }

    }
```

My Object class is like

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Host implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8445943548965154778L;


private String name;
private String email;
public Host(){
    super();
}
  public Host(String name, String email) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setEmail(email);
    }

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


}
```

I am posting the data like

```
{
"name": "user01",
"email":"user1@email.com"
}
```

from my Rest Client.But data is not printed in the backend. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (without my IDE) I do not see anything wrong, but I would remove some stuff, like consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} and the constructors in your object class. Try without that and tell me if it works :)

Comment: Actually when I print `System.out.println(host.getName());`. It prints nul.Any idea why?How to retrieve the received json data to java object value?

Comment: I test your code. Nothing is wrong. It works. May be your client side request is malformed. Can you share it?

Comment: Actually I am not developing any front end.So I am trying with Advanced Rest Client where I pass name and email as HTTP headers

Answer (score 1):

I use so effective solution to get post body as json. you can get body as string and convert it to your obejct(Host class) by using ObjectMapper as follow :

```
@RestController
    public class  DataInsertController {


        @RequestMapping(value = "data/api", consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<HostResponse> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> hostMap )  {

             // handle json object exceptions to validate input
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(hostMap);            
            Host host = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonObject.toString()  , Host.class);

            System.out.println(host.getName());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new HostResponse("token"));
        }
}
```

Comment: I think it's not needed as Spring uses the Jackson JSON library to automatically marshal instances into JSON

Comment: yes, it is not required but for invalid body return spring return error. by using Jackson JSON libraries, you can handle input and return appropriate response based on input body

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your class with the Jackson Annotations else it won't know which field to deserialise:

```
@JsonCreator
  public Host((@JsonProperty("name")String name,@JsonProperty("email") String email) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setEmail(email);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postman to send data then send data in body part instead of header as you have used @RequestBody to get the data.

This will solve your problem